# Initializing 2-D vector

Tags: c++

I have been trying to initialize a 2-D vector and I keep getting the error
"expected ',' or ';' or '{' before token", this occurs before the first bracket/after first line of code but if I add a semicolon to the end of the first line, I get another error saying "unqualified id before {". I do not know what syntax error I am making but any help would be appreciated as I assume this is a simple (hopeful) fix.

```
vector<vector<double> > IC40_events (10, vector<double> (8,0))
{    
    ifstream IC40_events_data("IC40_exp.dat", ios::in);

    while(IC40_events_data.good())
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {   
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            {
                IC40_events_data >> IC40_events[j][i];
            }
        }

        IC40_events_data.close();
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: is this a function declaration? "vector<vector<double> > IC40_events (10, vector<double> (8,0))". It needs the type and name of the variable, not its value.

Comment: I'm confused by your comment, this is suppose to declare a 2-D vector and I think putting (8,0) in parenthesis would enable the vector to initialized to 0 and have room for 8 elements?

Comment: It's ok, I was confused before but I understand now, before it looked like you were trying to create a function (as it had curly brackets after) rather than declare a vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put a semicolon after declaring the vector (as suggested by the error message).

```
vector< vector<double> > IC40_events (10, vector<double> (8,0));
```

Also, you should not need your rest of the code in the curly braces. Your final code should look like:

```
vector<vector<double> > IC40_events (10, vector<double> (8,0));    
ifstream IC40_events_data("IC40_exp.dat", ios::in);
while (IC40_events_data.good()) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {   
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
        {
            IC40_events_data >> IC40_events[j][i];
        }
    }
    IC40_events_data.close();
}
return(0);
```

Comment: This does not compile, it now says that there is an unqualified id before while

Comment: @mgkov18 Can you post the complete code with the error in the problem? I am not sure if the error lies here.

Comment: do you have #include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream> using namespace std; at the top of your file?

Comment: Yes, it works now. I just had to move the vector declaration inside the main